# GWT download external source

Tags: java, gwt, download

Using window.open to download a file. The request is hit to another application, once the file processing is completed on the application, retrieves the file from the application in the form of a stream.

The problem occurs intermittently. sometimes able to retrieve the file successfully and sometimes it the windows stays blank and stays open. I have checked the logs, things appear to be successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delayed reply, but was able to resolve the issue. The issue wasn’t on the client side (GWT). It was failing at the server side for some requests

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to make an own class for this?
It's just a wild guess, but I had a problem with window.alert one time with GWT.
When I used it a listener on the client side stopped working. I never found out why. I wrote an own class that created an message box and the problem was gone. I have the feeling that GWT has some problems that are hidden inside the framework.

Comment: For window open ? Could you please elaborate. Anyways is there a way to debug the call or find out where it's failing.